# Replace href value by getting current URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a menu in Wordpress that uses WP Menu system. All links are basically custom links that output the following (WP classes removed for brevity):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://mysite.com/about">About</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/about/#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/about/#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/about/#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>

<li><a href="http://mysite.com/services">Services</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to remove the domain part of the URL if the parent page is being viewed so if I were viewing the About page the links in the menu would change to:

```
<li><a href="http://mysite.com/about">About</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="http://mysite.com/services">Services</a>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-3">Section 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="http://mysite.com/services/#section-4">Section 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>

</ul>
```

The problem I have with jQuery is that I cannot target each specific page because the pages will be unknown, I therefore need it to get the URL and match it with the correct part of the menu to change the links. I have tried this but its too specific:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("about") != -1) {

  //do something

} else {

  //do something else

}
```

**EDIT**

I only want to alter the links in the menu for the current page. The answers so far change all of the link in the menu, I just want to target the links found on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option...

```
$(function() {
    $("a[href*='" + window.location.pathname + "#']").attr("href", function() {
        return "#" + this.href.split("#")[1];
    });
});
```

This will find all the links with the current page and a `#` in them and fix the href value accordingly.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't seem to be working. No URL's get replaced or changed from what I can see

Comment: Slight mistake on my part, not include the trailing `/` on the url.  I also changed `window.location.href` to `window.location.pathname` so it doesn't include the full url (with any # values and querystring).  That should be better now :)

Comment: I'm seeing a syntax error in dev tools that reads :syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=/cjo/testing//#] - Same error occurs if I remove the extra slash

Comment: That did it. I actually used your code but instead targeted just the links within the menu with a classname like @Krishna's answer suggested. Will this affect other page links do you think? I don't really understand whats happening with this code

Comment: Yeah, if you can add a class to the links or container then it's a much easier job, rather than messing about with searching in href values.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mpc7/)

Firstly add a class `sections` to the `ul` element to make it easy to target.

```
<ul class="sections">
    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/about/#section-1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/about/#section-2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/about/#section-3">Section 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Use `.map()` to replace the `href` for each anchor.

EDIT - based on your new update & I liked @Archer's update too. This should work.

```
$(".sections a[href* = '" + window.location.pathname + "/#']").map(function(){
    var currentsection = this.href.split('/').pop();
    this.href = currentsection;
});
```

Comment: @Archer - please advise such a scenario & i will fix it.

Comment: This is great however its changing all links in the menu rather than just the links found on the current page. See updated question to clear things up

Comment: Is there a way we could dynamically add the class name to the corect menu for the current page on view? That would fix it. For example: if on about page only add that class name to the about sub menu only.

Comment: @egr103 - I made the change based on your edit.. please try it.

Comment: Thanks but I get Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .sections a[href* = /cjo//#]

Comment: @egr103 add quotes around the href like this `a[href* = '/cjo/#']` ..Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('a').each(function(){
   // check the anchor tab href has location.href or not
   if($(this).attr('href').indexOf(window.location.href) != -1)
   {
       // some code to replace location.href to blank
       var href=$(this).attr('href').replace(window.location.href,'');
       $(this).attr('href',href);
   }
});
```

**Alternatively,** try this,

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if(this.href.indexOf('#') != -1)
   {
       var href=this.href.split('#')[1];
       this.href = '#'+href;
   }
});
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to wrap the native DOM element (the Anchor) in a jQuery object.  `this.href = this.href.replace(window.location.href,'');` does the same thing.

Comment: Both code samples bring an error: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined